# Access: Increment/Decrement a number with 2 dots

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two fields for current version number and previous version number in a form. What I want to do is when I enter the current version number (which is written like this 18.04.15), the previous version number on the next text box to automatically fill itself with 18.04.**14**.

I tried:
 `=[txtCurrentVersion]-1` in the control source, but obviously because I'm not decrementing by one, it didn't work.

Would appreciate some guidance, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code splits the text based on dot and subracts one from last item.

```
Private Sub txtCurrentVersion_AfterUpdate()
    If Nz(Me.txtCurrentVersion, "") <> "" Then
        Me.txtPrevVersion.Value = Split(Me.txtCurrentVersion, ".")(0) & "." & Split(Me.txtCurrentVersion, ".")(1) & "." & Split(Me.txtCurrentVersion, ".")(2) - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @TomerbBarzilay  Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a function where you give the function 3 parameters, the 1st is the current version number string, the 2nd is the version number level (0 for major number,  1 for subversion number and 2 for minor version number) and the value to increase or decrease.

for example:

```
Function ModifyVersion(VersionNumber, NumberLevel, Number)

If VersionNumber <> "" AND NumberLevel >= 0 AND NumberLevel < 3 Then

    dim VersionArray
    VersionArray = Split(VersionNumber, ".")

    Select Case NumberLevel
    Case 0
        VersionArray(0) = VersionArray(0) + Number
    Case 1
        VersionArray(1) = VersionArray(1) + Number
    Case 2
        VersionArray(2) = VersionArray(2) + Number
    End Select

    ModifyVersion = VersionArray(0) & "." & VersionArray(1) & "." & VersionArray(2)

    End If

End Function
```

Then to decrease one from the minor version number use:

```
VersionNumber = [txtCurrentVersion]
Dim UpdateVersion
UpdateVersion = ModifyVersion(VersionNumber, 2, -1)
```